# Automatic zoom on a specific node in a mapping with d3.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, vuetify.js, zooming

I have a mapping with d3 nodes (they correspond to actors). I made a search bar, that allows me to search for actors. When I select one actor via the search bar, it highlights in the mapping (with a yellow halo.
What I would like is an automatic zoom on the node (actor) as soon as it is selected (keeping the yellow halo).

Here's the method that handles the yellow halo on the selected actor.

```
actorSearched: function () {
  // if actor selected in autocomplete
  if (this.actorSearched != "" && this.actorSearched) {
    //reset radius when switching to one actor to another
    if (this.lastSearchedNodeHtmlElement) {
      this.lastSearchedNodeHtmlElement.setAttribute("r", this.lastSearchedNodeDefaultRadius)
      this.lastSearchedNodeCoords = []
    }
    //reset vars
    this.lastSearchedNodeDefaultRadius = 0
    this.lastSearchedNodeHtmlElement = ""
    //get the searched node's html elem
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-group")
    let elementsArray = [].slice.call(elements);
    let searchedElement = elementsArray.filter((obj) => {
      return (
        ([this.actorSearched].includes(obj.id))
      );
    });
    // set variables
    this.lastSearchedNodeDefaultRadius = searchedElement[0].firstChild.getAttribute("r")
    this.lastSearchedNodeHtmlElement = searchedElement[0].firstChild
    searchedElement[0].firstChild.setAttribute("r", "25px")
    this.getNode(this.lastSearchedNodeHtmlElement.__data__.id)
    // parse node coords
    let coordsRaw = searchedElement[0].getAttribute("transform")
    coordsRaw = coordsRaw.substring(10)
    coordsRaw = coordsRaw.slice(0, -1)
    this.lastSearchedNodeCoords = coordsRaw.split(",")
}
```

As you can see, for the yellow halo, I just increase the size of a yellow node behind the node that needs to be "highlighted". So I would like a zoom on the selected node (actor) but I really don't know how to do it using d3.

Here's what it looks like when an actor is selected, I would like a big zoom on it.[image]